# Send Message in Teams Chat/Channel as a User

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-graph-teams

Trying to send out chat message from Bot with sender as a current logged in user. I am able to implement this with graph api using On Behalf of flow. However the API is still in Beta and don't think we can use it in production setting.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Is there a different way? Can we use ConnectorClient? Tried this, but the chat message is sent by the bot instead of the current logged in user. I am not able to create user token with botframework.com. It is always bot or the registered app.

Do anyone know if there is a way to accomplish this avoiding the graph beta api?

Comment: Yes you're correct, the API is available in BETA at this point and its not suitable for production ready. Its worth to wait till it becomes GA/V1.0 so that you can make use of that in production. Also you can use connecterclient, but it will show the message is send by the bot only.

Comment: Any idea how to find out when this will be available in GA/v1.0?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not documented. But you can do this. Consider checking the [Graph API changelogs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/changelog) where they usually update if the beta is promoted to v1.0

Comment: Thanks for all the help!!